# Find last occurence matching condition in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I can't find out which method to use for finding the last element of an array matching a condition.

This should work but that doesn't seems to be the best way:

```
array.reverse.find {condition}

array[array.rindex {condition}]
```

Would expect something like array.rfind {condition}...

Comment: Hello Léon, Welcome to SO. `arr.reverse.find { condition }` is working for me, do you have an error in your code?? can you post your code?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla The question wasn't "why isn't this working?", the question was "Is there a better way of doing it?"

Comment: Hi Alejandro, thanks a lot! It works perfectly for me too but I expected Ruby to have a dedicated method for this... but it looks like arr.reverse_each.find {condition} may be the more appropriated way

Answer (score 2):

`array.rindex(condition)` will give the last matching element index no. 
This will give you last matching element

```
array[array.rindex(condition)]
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but I was wondering if there exists a way to do this using only one method, something like array.rfind(condition) or array.find_last(condition)

Answer (score 1):

I think reduce would do the job.

```
array.reduce { |accumulator, element| condition ? element : accumulator }
```

This way, the returned value will be the last value assigned to the accumulator.

Beware that the accumulator always starts off with the first element of the enumerable, so if you would like to return nil if none of the elements satisfy the condition, you would have to pass that as as argument to reduce like so:

```
array.reduce(nil) { |accumulator, element| condition ? element : accumulator }
```